# Selenium Not opening website with scripts

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to open the website: http://maps.address.gov.sa/Home/Index?lang=en with selenium but it doesn't open completely [image: Doesn't load map]

It used to open completely until a day ago, I have tried running the same selenium code 2 different machines and am still getting this error. Is this a case of javascript not loading? or is it local problem

Comment: Update the question with your _code trials_ and the _error stack trace_

Comment: What `error` you are getting?

Comment: can you open it without selenium at the same time?